# Splitting an array into 2 parts

Tags: c#, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I am attempting to read a log file in this format:

```
date | cost
date | cost
..ect
```

Using the following code to read the file in to an array:

`string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("log.txt");`

My question is how do I slice the array in to 2 parts per line so that I can add them to a list view of 2 columns? I was thinking perhaps a dictionary would be a good start..

Comment: A little more code showing what you have done would be a good way to get better responses

Comment: Your question is tagged 'c', but in your question, you use a line of C# code. So, which language do you use?

Comment: @ProgramFOX C? I'm sure i tagged as C# :/ oops, guess I will re-tag if I can

Answer (score 1):

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("log.txt").Select(l=> l.Split('|'));
var dictionary= lines.ToDictionary(x => x[0], y => y[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is C# rather than C, the following may do what you're looking for:

```
public class LogEntry{

    public string Date;
    public string Cost;


    public LogEntry(string date,string cost){
        Date=date;
        Cost=cost;
    }

}

...

// Grab the lines from the file:
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("log.txt");

// Create our output set:
LogEntry[] logEntries=new LogEntry[lines.Length];

// For each line in the file:
for(int i=0;i<lines.Length;i++){
    // Split the line:
    string[] linePieces=lines[i].Split('|');

    // Safety check - make sure this is a line we want:
    if(linePieces.Length!=2){
        // No thanks!
        continue;
    }

    // Create the entry:
    logEntries[i]=new LogEntry( linePieces[0] , linePieces[1] );
}

// Do something with logEntries.
```

Note that this sort of processing should only be done with a *relatively small* log file. File.ReadAllLines("log.txt") becomes very inefficient with large files, at which point using a raw FileStream is more suitable.

Comment: Side note: The safety check may generate nulls in the logEntries array. It could be converted into a List<LogEntry> instead, but may not perform as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 2D array and `string.Split('-')`

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("log.txt");
//Create an array with lines.Length rows and 2 columns
string[,] table = new string[lines.Length,2];
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
     //Split the line in 2 with the | character
     string[] parts = lines[i].Split('|');
     //Store them in the array, trimming the spaces off
     table[i,0] = parts[0].Trim();
     table[i,1] = parts[1].Trim();
}
```

Now you will have an array that looks like this:

```
table[date, cost]
```

You could use a dictionary so you only have to look up the date if you want to improve it. *EDIT:* As @[Damith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19336726/1218281) has done

Additionally, with [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx) you could simplify this into:

```
var table = File.ReadAllLines("log.txt").Select(s => s.Split('|')).ToDictionary(k => k[0].TrimEnd(' '), v => v[1].TrimStart(' '));
```

Which you can now easily get the results from the LINQ expression with:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kv in table)
{
      Console.WriteLine("Key: " + kv.Key + " Value: " + kv.Value);
}
```

Also note if you do not need the spaces in your file you can omit the `Trim()`s

Answer (score 0):

And just because this post was *originally* tagged ***C :)***
Here is a C example:

With a data file (I called it temp.txt) that looks like this:

```
3/13/56 | 13.34
3/14/56 | 14.14
3/15/56 | 15.00
3/16/56 | 16.56
3/17/56 | 17.87
3/18/56 | 18.34
3/19/56 | 19.31
3/20/56 | 20.01
3/21/56 | 21.00
```

This code will read it, parse it into a single 2 dim string array, `char col[2][80][20];`

```
#include <ansi_c.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char *buf;
    char line[260];
    char col[2][80][20];
   FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen("c:\\dev\\play\\temp.txt", "r");
   i=-1;
   while(fgets(line, 260, fp))
   {
        i++;
        buf = strtok(line, "|");
        if(buf) strcpy(col[0][i], buf);
        buf = strtok(NULL, "|");
        if(buf) strcpy(col[1][i], buf);
   }
   fclose(fp);

   return 0;
}
```